# How to underline text without bullets

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to only underline the text in an (un)ordered list? Specifically, say, I have a  menu, displayed inline without bullets where every item is a link. The links aren't underlined, but they get underlined when the user hovers over them. Then they get underlined with the invisible bullet point, which bugs me. Is there a way to only underline the text?

ANSWER: Turns out, my problem wasn't in the bullets. Moreover, it was so dumb, that I am now ashamed of this question. I thought I remembered everything that was coded, but it turned out that I had a `&nbsp;` before the list items out of some strange reason. I kept everything as it was, but changed the :hover from acting on the `<a>` tags to the `<span>` tags with a "hover" class which surrounded the text, leaving out the `&nbsp;`. Now everything's fine and I only get the text underlined. Thank you to @Ken Clark for pointing out the `<span>` "trick".

Comment: My post in this page here will meet all your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove underline from `a:hover` and inside link place your text in a span and give underline style to that span:
Example:

```
<style>
.anchor
{
    text-decoration:none;
}

.anchor:hover
{
    text-decoration:none;
}
.spnItem:hover
{

    text-decoration:underline;
}
</style>
<a href="#" class="anchor"><span class="spnItem">Item</span> </a>
```

Comment: Thanks, the span solved my problem. It wasn't in the bullets. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to understand what exactly you are asking.

If you don't want the bullets in unordered list

```
<ul type="none">  <u><li>one</li></u>  <u><li>two</li></u>  <u><li>three</li></u></ul>
```

Setting the type as none will remove the bullets.

```
<ul style="list-style-type:none">
```

The above will work perfectly. Because type:none may not be accepted by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Set the list-style to none for your ul:

```
ul { list-style: none }
```

The underline on hover won't underline where the bullet used to be. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yLYww/) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wMSFp/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a>Link</a></li>
    <li><a>Link</a></li>
    <li><a>Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

This will only underline the link, not the bullet as well. If you only want it underlined on hover then change the CSS to:

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    text-underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```css
ul li
{
    list-style:none;
}


a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a>Link</a></li>
    <li><a>Link</a></li>
    <li><a>Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: don't use jsfiddle links, stackoverflow supports html. you need to use that.